# Ideal number of Object Instances to pass Via View Model constructor (dependency injection)

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, mvvm-light

I am implementing a project, main objective is to have loosely coupled class implementations, for example below,  i am using simple IOC container to inject PageNavigation and AppConfig instance into the view model.

```
public MyViewModel(IPageNavigationService PageNavigation, IAppConfig AppConfig) {
   //my code
}
```

1. is there a limit to number of instances i can pass via constructor? , which may cause unforeseen  problems .
2. what if i would have 5 to 6 object instances i need to pass, is there any other way i can access the object instance other than constructor, keeping things loosely coupled and dynamic, and all View model's using default instance (singleton ) of the object being passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no limit of instances to pass to your viewmodel instance via a constructor. You should pass all dependencies, that are required for your ViewModel to work properly via the constructor.

Dependencies that are optional or providing a diffrent implementation can be passed by PropertyInjection.

You could also define a constructor to get a reference to the IOC-Container, so that the ViewModel resolves the necessary dependencies by itself in the constructor. But then has your viewmodel a dependency to the container what is not required sometimes.

```
public MyViewModel(IocContainer container) {
   // resolve dependencies via the container
}
```